# airflow scheduler goes down

Tags: python, rabbitmq, airflow

After some attempt I found that the most stable installation is composed by

```
AIRFLOW 1.8
ERLANG 19.2 + RABBITMQ 3.6.7
PYTHON 2.7
```

Everything works almost fine but I still got some bad issues, the most dramatic one happens when I start a DAG using the panel.

In this case something happens to the scheduler which stops working, If I restart it, anything keep working with not issues, if you are using

[airflow-scheduler-failover-controller](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-scheduler-failover-controller)

the scheduler is restarted automatically and perhaps you never noticed the problem. Regardless you are noticing or not it, actually it is still in airflow and still kills the scheduler everytime you start a DAG from the panel; fortunately you don't have to start a dag by hand so often.

After long investigation the problem raises when AIRFLOW is asking for a job status:

info celery_executor.py:

```
 83     def sync(self):
 84 
 85         self.logger.debug(
 86             "Inquiring about {} celery task(s)".format(len(self.tasks)))
 87
 88         for key, async in list(self.tasks.items()):
 90             state = async.state <---- HERE
```

async.state raise exception due to a connection reset, this happens after the queue have been created. As far I know when async.state get called the TCP channel has been already closed.

Into wireshare logs I can see that:
**172.1.0.2 -> rabbitmq node, 172.1.0.1 -> airflow node**
[image]

Does anybody fixed this ?

Comment: You should consider posting this information as an Airflow issue.

Comment: Done. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1029